# Delegate one interface to multiple implementations

Tags: kotlin, delegates

Could a class delegate an interface to multiple implementations with a few lines? Given this interface:

```
interface Foo {
  fun doA()
  fun doB()
}
```

The following class would compile for a single delegate:

```
class FooImpl(delegate: Foo): Foo by delegate
```

Although useless, it generates java bytecode for what is should do: delegate `Foo` -> `Foo`.

Could this be possible for a list of delegates as well? Such that it delegates `Foo` -> `List<Foo>`. Like:

```
class FooImpl(delegates: List<Foo>): Foo by delegates
```

Right now, our codebase is filled with classes such as:

```
class FooImpl(private val delegates: List<Foo>): Foo {
   override fun doA() { delegates.forEach { it.doA() } 
   override fun doB() { delegates.forEach { it.doB() } 
}
```

It feels like busy work and it's unnecessarily error prone, plus it creates unneeded work for the dev writing the code and the dev reviewing the code. I'm aware it can become complex for return values, but that will never be the case. In the current code,  there's always a set of an interface, 2 actual implementations and a root implementation filled with `doA() { delegates.forEach { it.doA() }` .
Could this be simplified using Kotlin?

Comment: What would it do for methods returning a value?

Comment: i see composite pattern

Comment: @gidds For the problem in general, I could think of severals solutions like the first of the list or the quickest to return. For this specific problem: no function will return a value.

Comment: @sidgate Searching for 'composite pattern kotlin' results in finding solutions similarly to what we already have, as shown in the last code block. This tells me there is not a more concise way possible, right?